# Constant Expected "{" before ")" token

Tags: iphone, ios

I've got a little problem. I am applying some changes to an iOS program i wrote, but I've struck a problem. I constantly get a "Expected '{' before ')' token" warning, but my coding skills aren't good enough to find the problem. A little help would greatly be appreciated.

```
#import "Search.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"

    //button
    - (IBAction)buttonPressed)sender{
    RootViewController *newview = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5]; 
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFl ipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES]; 
    [self.view addSubview:newview.view]; 
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    @implementation Search
@end
```

Comment: You also need to put your buttonPressed method *inside* the @implementation block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed)sender{
```

Should be

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
```

And you need a } after

```
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Like:

```
[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax would be

```
#import "Search.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"


  @implementation Search
//button
 - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
        RootViewController *newview = [[RootViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5]; 
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES]; 
        [self.view addSubview:newview.view]; 
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

@end
```

Comment: You forgot your : after the method name. buttonPressed:(id)sender

Answer (score 0):

You are not completting the code block `- (IBAction)buttonPressed)sender{`.  You need an end brace (`}`) somewhere to tell the code where the `buttonPressed` method ends.